# Menu fixando de forma brusca

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tenho um menu que após scroll ganha uma classe .fixed que faz com que ele fixe. Funciona, porém o menu fixa de uma forma muito brusca e até mesmo o scroll da página fica prejudicado já que ela se adequa ao novo atributo "fixed" do menu.

1. Como faço para deixar o efeito de fixar mais suave?
2. Como impedir que o scroll da página fique prejudicado quando o menu fixar?

   ```
   <ul class="menu">

       <li class="flex"><a href="">INICIAL</a></li>
       <li class="flex"><a href="">ONDE ESTAMOS</a></li>
       <li class="flex"><a href="">SOBRE NÓS</a></li>
       <li class="flex"><a href="">CONTATO</a></li>

   </ul>
   ```

CSS

```
.fixar {
z-index: 9999;
position: fixed;
top: -5%;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
width: 100%;
}

.fixar + .menu {
 padding-top: 102px;
}     
.menu{
background: #fefefe;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 70%;
padding: 1.2%;
margin-top: 3%;
border-radius: 2%;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 13px 35px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 13px 35px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 13px 35px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 }
```

JQUERY

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var nav = $('.menu');

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
            nav.addClass("fixar");
        } else {
            nav.removeClass("fixar");
        }
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use um `.fadeIn()` para suavizar a aparição do menu quando ele fixar. Em relação a "prejudicar o scroll", como apenas pelo código mostrado não dá pra reproduzir o real funcionamento da página, pode ser que aplicando um `padding-top` no `body` no mesmo valor em que o menu ocupa no flow da página, resolva. Aí você tem que testar no seu código e talvez fazer algum ajuste.

Também é preciso fazer um `else if` para que as condições não sejam chamadas mais de uma vez. Além de verificar se o scroll é maior que `300`, verificar tammbém se contém a classe `.fixar`:

```js
var nav = $('.menu');

$(window).scroll(function () {
   // pega a altura do menu (com margens e tudo)
    var nav_height = nav.outerHeight(true);
     if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300 && !nav.hasClass("fixar")) {
        $("body").css("padding-top", nav_height+"px");
         nav
         .hide()
         .addClass("fixar")
         .fadeIn(200);
     } else if($(this).scrollTop() <= 300 && nav.hasClass("fixar")) {
        $("body").css("padding", "0");
         nav
         .removeClass("fixar");
     }
});
```

```css
.fixar {
z-index: 9999;
position: fixed;
top: -5%;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
width: 100%;
}

.fixar + .menu {
 padding-top: 102px;
}     
.menu{
background: #fefefe;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 70%;
padding: 1.2%;
margin-top: 3%;
border-radius: 2%;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 13px 35px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 13px 35px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 13px 35px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">

    <li class="flex"><a href="">INICIAL</a></li>
    <li class="flex"><a href="">ONDE ESTAMOS</a></li>
    <li class="flex"><a href="">SOBRE NÓS</a></li>
    <li class="flex"><a href="">CONTATO</a></li>

</ul>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

> Esse CSS `.fixar + .menu {` é inválido porque a classe `.menu` não é
>   uma irmã adjacente da classe `.fixar`. Portanto não tem efeito algum.

Answer (score 1):

Com o código abaixo você consegue fazer o menu fixo quando dar scroll de uma maneira bem simples.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.top-container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="top-container">
  <h1>Scroll Down</h1>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<div class="header" id="myHeader">
  <h2>My Header</h2>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>On Scroll Sticky Header</h3>
  <p>The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Scroll back up to remove the sticky effect.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>

<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```